# strength of each dipole charge

Tags: electric-fields, singularities, dipole, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

If I have a two dimensional dipole whose line charges are located on the y axis, I know that the electric flux through a gaussian pill box containing both the charges will be zero, that is

\begin{gather*}
\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A} = 0
\end{gather*}

This makes sense as the net charge inside the contour is 0. However, how can I quantify the strength of each individual charge? Initially I think that I should compute the flux through the half the cylinder whose cross section is shown in red. However, because the electric field is singular at the origin, I don't think the integral is finite. If I change the cross section to the one in blue, then the singularity is excluded, but I cannot quantify the strength of the charge.

So how does one quantify the strength of the charges that make up a dipole, or any higher order multipole?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The path integral of $\vec{E}$ around _any_ loop will be zero, since $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ for an electrostatic field (and Stokes' Theorem.)  You need to do a _surface_ integral (i.e., a flux integral) and use Gauss's Law to determine the amount of charge inside.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You're right. I corrected the question but do you know how it would be possible to determine the individual charge per unit length of each line charge? How can I quantify a single line charge that makes up a dipole?

Comment: A true dipole is the limit of two charges $q$ that approach each other to a distance $\delta x$ such that their product $p=q\cdot \delta x$ remains constant. That means you will have infinite charge for a "real" dipole ($\delta x \rightarrow 0$) - and if they are a finite distance apart, it just depends on their distance. What exactly are you trying to do? I think I don't understand your "two dimensional dipole with line charges" concept. Can you explain?

Comment: @Floris I am studying a related problem where the quantity of interest is governed by the Laplace equation and analogous to the electric potential. My problem is 2D in the sense that there is no change in the $z$ direction, i.e. two line charges that extend to positive and negative infinity in the $z$ direction. Therefore I only consider an cross section in the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: OK - are these finite line charges that are a finite distance apart? Do I understand correctly that they lie along the Z axis?

Comment: However for my problem, the physical problem is not periodic and lies in a wedge domain bounded between $\phi_1 \leq \theta \leq  \phi_2$. Because of this, I am looking for a way to characterize only a portion of the dipole. In this question I was wondering if the flux out of a surface that does not contain the whole dipole is finite. I supposed that dipoles are normally characterized by $p = q\cdot \delta x$ being constant, but what does this quantity physically represent? what physical quantity does distance multiplied by charge represent?

Comment: @floris I am using the multipole expansion as the general solution to the Laplace equation. So I believe that the charges lie on the $z$ axis for the dipole potential field. I think i see where you are going. If the charges are a finite distance apart, then they have a finite quantifiable charge density. However if they are not a finite distance apart, then individually, the charges are singular with a value of infinity

Comment: If they are indeed not a finite distance apart, you cannot quantify their value - only the product of charge and distance remains finite. This is why you are running into a problem - you are trying to get the value of an infinite quantity (cancelled by an equal and opposite infinite quantity). That is unfortunately meaningless.